# Flask SQL Alchemy create_all doesn't create any tables

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I was working on my school project which required me to develop an API on Flask. I was using MySQL with Flask SQLAlchemy. After I finished the project I haven't touched it in a month. When I came back and tried to run it I found out that it doesn't create tables on its own.

What I checked:

- MySQL user has all permitions
- App does connect to the database
- Every model has table name defined

`app.py` file:

```py
import logging
from os import environ

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from config import DevConfig, ProdConfig

db = SQLAlchemy()


def create_app():
    from resources import Area, Map, Ping, SensorData

    env = environ.get('ENVIRONMENT')
    if env == 'DEVELOPMENT':
        Config = DevConfig
    else:
        Config = ProdConfig

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config())
    CORS(app)
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='app.log',
        level=logging.INFO
    )

    api = Api(app)
    api.add_resource(Area, '/area')
    api.add_resource(Map, '/map')
    api.add_resource(SensorData, '/api/v1/saveSensorData')
    api.add_resource(Ping, '/ping')

    db.init_app(app)

    with app.app_context():
        from models import AreaModel, SensorDataModel
        db.create_all()

    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

One of the models:

```py
from app import db
from datetime import datetime


class AreaModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'area_records'

    id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        primary_key=True
    )
    aqi = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
    )
    latitude = db.Column(
        db.String(16),
    )
    longitude = db.Column(
        db.String(16),
    )
    created = db.Column(
        db.DateTime,
        default=datetime.now()
    )
```

Comment: You haven't shown an example table. Do those classes inherit from `db.Model`?

Comment: @roganjosh I've updated the post with one of the models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but not an answer. For some reason, when I run `app.py` directly using `python app.py` it won't create any tables. But when I created `run.py` with this code:

```py
from app import create_app

app = create_app()

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

It worked! I hope someone can explain it but I'm really happy I got the solution.